# Homebrew のインストールに失敗する

Tags: macos, homebrew

Homebrew インストール時に、完了できませんでした。

どういうことでしょうか、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

```
略

* [new tag]             3.2.9                  -> 3.2.9
HEAD is now at 890190c0f Merge pull request #12310 from Bo98/yard
==> Tapping homebrew/core
remote: Enumerating objects: 1065030, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (154/154), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (106/106), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Failed during: git fetch --force origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

```
 ~ % brew -v

Homebrew 3.2.17-133-g890190c
Homebrew/homebrew-core (no Git repository)
```

```
 ~ % brew doctor

Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Homebrew/homebrew-core was not tapped properly! Run:
  rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
  brew tap homebrew/core

Warning: Some taps are not on the default git origin branch and may not receive
updates. If this is a surprise to you, check out the default branch with:
  git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew インストール時に通信が失敗した結果、デフォルトの [tap](https://docs.brew.sh/Taps) である homebrew/core の情報のダウンロードに失敗しています。通信が失敗しているというのは `error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54` から分かります。

一度 Homebrew をアンインストールして再度インストール手順を試すか、brew doctor の警告文にあるように homebrew/core のダウンロードを再度試してみてください。

```sh
rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
brew tap homebrew/core
```

再度試しても全く同じエラーが再現する場合、errno から推測するにネットワーク環境の問題が考えられます。環境を見直すか、違うネットワーク環境から試してみてください。参考: ["Homebrew on macOS: brew update says LibreSSL error: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61694161/5989200)

Comment: ありがとうございます!!
解決できました！